# php composer cannot "see" mysqli extension (is installed)

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mysqli

after installing phpmyadmin with php8.0.8 (used this article https://www.itzgeek.com/how-tos/linux/centos-how-tos/how-to-install-phpmyadmin-on-rhel-8.html)
i keep getting this error "Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require the following PHP extensions to be installed: mysqli"
when doing php --ini all seems good
and also php -m seems good
any ideas why?
thanks

Comment: Try `yum install php-pdo`

Comment: getting this:Package php-pdo-7.2.24-1.module+el8.2.0+4601+7c76a223.x86_64 is already installed.
Dependencies resolved.

Comment: Weird. That's what usually provides mysqli in the RHEL flavor. Try `php -i | grep mysqli`

Comment: /etc/php.d/30-mysqli.ini,
mysqli
mysqli.allow_local_infile => On => On
mysqli.allow_persistent => On => On
mysqli.default_host => no value => no value
mysqli.default_port => 3306 => 3306
mysqli.default_pw => no value => no value
mysqli.default_socket => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock => /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
mysqli.default_user => no value => no value
mysqli.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect => Off => Off
mysqli.rollback_on_cached_plink => Off => Off
API Extensions => mysqli,pdo_mysql

Comment: So it is installed then. I'm not sure why Composer can't see it